# Omit action in "if" statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm getting my hands dirty with Rxjs with some strings and objects in order to learn it.

I'm trying to dynamically create key/values in an empty declared object, using a string variable.

In this approach, what I want to do is the following: Iterate the whole string, including spaces and commas.

If a letter is already in the object, increment its value, otherwise, add it.

So I came up with the following piece of code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-js-letttesr-cool-commas-not-cool?file=index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { ReplaySubject, from } from "rxjs";
import { tap, reduce } from "rxjs/operators";

// string
const str =  "I am afraid I can not do that, Dave";
//string no spaces
let strNoSpace = str.replace(/\s+/g, ''); 

from(strNoSpace).pipe(
  reduce((acc, value) => {
    if(acc[value] !== undefined) {
      acc[value] = acc[value] + 1;
    } else {
      acc[value] = 1;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {}),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-swgek8?file=index.ts)